# Testing rxjs subscription in react using jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, jestjs

I am trying to test the below code

Slider.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ISlide } from "./ISlide";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject, timer } from "rxjs";
import { repeatWhen, take, takeUntil, takeWhile, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

interface ISliderProps {
  ...
}

const SliderWrapper = styled.ul`
  ...
`;

const SliderItem = styled.li`
  ...
`;

export const Slider = (props: ISliderProps) => {

  const {
    slides,
    activeSlide = 0,
    onActiveItemChange,
    itemsPerPage = 1,
    delay = 5000,
    interval = 5000,
    loop = true
  } = props;

  const [currentActiveSlide, setCurrentActiveSlide] = useState(activeSlide);
  const sliderCount = Math.ceil(slides.length / itemsPerPage);
  const timerStart$: Observable<null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  const timerStop$: Observable<null> = new Subject<null>();
  const timer$ = timer(delay, interval).pipe(
    takeWhile(() => loop),
    takeUntil(timerStop$),
    repeatWhen(() => timerStart$)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerSubscription = timer$.subscribe({
      next: (i) => {
        const nextSlide = i >= sliderCount ? i % sliderCount : i;
        onActiveItemChange(nextSlide);
        setCurrentActiveSlide(nextSlide);
      }
    });
    return () => timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const handleSliderItemClick = (i: number) => {
    setCurrentActiveSlide(i);
    timerStop$.next(null);
    timer(delay).pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(timerStart$.next(null))
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SliderWrapper>
        {currentActiveSlide}
        {slides.map(({ id }, i) =>
          <SliderItem
            key={id}
            aria-label={"scroll page number " + id}
            onClick={() => handleSliderItemClick(i)}
            active={i === currentActiveSlide}
          />)}
      </SliderWrapper>
    </>
  );
};
```

Below is my test

```
import React from "react";
import { Slider } from "../../../components/slider/Slider";
import renderer, { act } from "react-test-renderer";
import { ISlide } from "../../../components/slider/ISlide";

it("renders without crashing", done => {
  const slides: ISlide[] = [
    { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }
  ];

  act(() => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Slider itemsPerPage={3} slides={slides} activeSlide={0} />);
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    done();
  });

});
```

I have called done but the test keeps returning a warning

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

As expected the problem is in the subscription

```
 ●  Timeout

      67 |
      68 |   useEffect(() => {
    > 69 |     const timerSubscription = timer$.subscribe({
         |                                      ^
      70 |       next: (i) => {
      71 |         const nextSlide = i >= sliderCount ? i % sliderCount : i;
      72 |         onActiveItemChange(nextSlide);
```

How do I unsubscribe from this subscription?

Comment: AFAIK the `timer` observable uses `setInterval`, so I think you'll have to use [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).